# Node.js Server running really slow

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, performance, express

I have a small node.js Server with around five routes. The Server acts like a Proxy. It receives requests and makes another request to a translator service.

Under a small load (10-15 people) requests are taking over 4sec<.

I already use caching for one of the routes. The route with caching is running fine.
On my test system, all routes have normal response speeds of around 180ms.

Here is a route that is slow under load:

```
app.post("/translate", urlencodedParser, async (req, res) => {
  let utf8 = Buffer.from(req.body.text, 'utf-8').toString('utf8');
  const authKey = API_KEY_VALUE;
  const textToTranslate = utf8;
  const targetLang = req.body.target_lang;
  const formality = req.body.formality;
  const preserveFormatting = 1;
  const data = new URLSearchParams();

  data.append('text', textToTranslate);
  data.append('target_lang', targetLang);
  data.append('formality', formality);
  data.append('preserve_formatting', preserveFormatting);

  const response = await axios.post('https://translator.com/v2/translate', data, {
       headers: {
         Authorization: `${authKey}`,
       },
    })
    .then(({ data }) => {
       return data;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });
      res.send({
      ...response
    });
});
```

I can't figure out the bottleneck. Would be amazing if you could give some directions or even a solution.

Comment: There is nothing in node making this slow,  it's more likely `translator.com` throttling your requests.

Comment: Initially, I thought the same but unfortunately, this was not the reason.

Comment: _"Initially, I thought the same but unfortunately, this was not the reason."_ How did you verify it?